# Any way to detect via code when an Internet firewall's access authorization dialog pops up (Windows)?

Tags: delphi, port, firewall

I have a Delphi 6 application that accesses local and external internet resources.  The code has timers that are set to certain reasonable values for connecting to those resources.  The problem is, ZoneAlarm and other firewalls will pop up a dialog box asking the user to authorize a program requesting internet access.  If the user waits too long to respond to the dialog box my timers time out and throw an Exception.  If I could tell when the dialog is open from code I could pause the timer until the user responds to the dialog box.  Does anyone know of a way, perhaps through the Windows API, to know when an internet access request is awaiting authorization?

This is only a problem of course the first time a user runs my program or a changed version of the program, but it's enough of a bother that I'd like to solve it.  If it is not possible to do this, then I'd like to hear from those of you that also have time-outs in your code for accessing the internet, the strategies you came up with to cope with this problem.

Comment: catch the exception and retry connection or add the program to firewall exception list?

Comment: @Dorin, this is more the answer than a comment. I'll vote it up because I think the best you can do is, as you say, to add your program to the white list of the Windows Firewall (and all the others you know how to do) and then just catch the connection exceptions because there is a plenty of firewall software with different block popups and whitelist handling.

Comment: @TLama yes, but I'm not here for the points, I'm here to share and learn (: